# unexpected reserved word error in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

i build this application based on ionic to run at android/ios.

i run my app with ionic serve, and it's run ok.

When i run with

```
ionic run android -l -c -s
```

i got this error
[image: ionic error]

i have no clue on this. already search stack and googling about this error but found nothing related. please help me if i miss something.